# Grouping by attribute sum in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a polygonal layer, with adjacent and non adjacent territories. Each territorie has a population field. I would like to create a new polygonal layer based on location and attribute : adjacent territories with a population sum under eg 600.000 inhabitants.

I can first select objects with population over eg 20.000 inhabitants. But then?

I tried the "Select by attribute sum" tool, but it didn't work (failure message).

[image]

(The colours depend on the number of inhabitants.)

Comment: Can I see a screenshot of your map and your table,  I think I know a way to do this but I am a tad confused about exactly what you are doing

Comment: The new polygon layer you want to show all polygons that have more than 600,000 population that are adjacent to what?  I dont exactly follow what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to dissolve all adjacent territories with a population of atleast 20,000 to their neighboring territory that has a population over 600,000 and get a sum of that pop count?  You mention you selected polys with pop over 20k but why?

Comment: I wasn't clear enough, Im' sorry.

Comment: The final purpose is to propose a new service to the population. This service depends on population density. There are 3 "levels of service" : 1 for the most dense areas, 1 for the intermediate, 1 for the least dense areas. But I have a limited number of services...I first selected the densest area and their immediate vicinity, and this gave me the first level of service area. The picture above shows the remaining territories I have to divide, to obtains 40 areas with no more than 600.000 inhabitants and 20 aeras with no more than 200.000.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to provide any requested clarifications.